# How to keep an email out of a recipient's spam folder?

Tags: email, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

When I user completes a form the information is sent to a specific email address which varies (and is not always on the same host).

The SMTP I am using is gmail which originates from my website host.

I have also specified Reply-To (which is the users email address entered in the form).

The problem is that the email is going straight into the SPAM folder.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Some useful resources: https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=81126 http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-15.html http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business http://spam.abuse.net/marketerhelp/

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.xequte.com/support/maillistking/spamissues.html) has an excellent breakdown of the most common reasons your email is being flagged as spam:

- Avoid common Spam words and phrases
- Send individual messages to each recipient
- If possible send via your ISP's mail server rather than using a local SMTP Server
- Stagger the delivery of your messages
- Minimize your use of attachments

Since the email is making it as far as the recipient, it's most likely the first, second, or last reason in this list.