# My domain emails are marked as SPAM in Gmail? How to solve this issue?

Tags: web-development, spam, spam-prevention, spamming

At Pro Webmasters I searched for an issue which relates to spammed domain list for sending emails which end up in the Spam box in Gmail. I found the link something like below:

[how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam%22how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

which says the reasons for the domain being listed as spam and I hardly found any solutions to come out that problem for the domain which was affected.

In my scenario the mails from my domain from the last few days are landing in SPAM box in Google whereas the rest like Yahoo/MSN/Rediff are OK. Even the plain text emails are going to SPAM Which is something of a surprise to me. I tried to find out the solutions overcome this problem but nobody gives exact steps to follow to solve this issue.

I request fellow members not to close this as duplicate, if you read my problem you can understand that this thread is all about steps to solve the issue of SPAM not the reasons. If you find similar questions please let me know or else try to answer my question.

Comment: If nobody gives exact steps then create two more questions: "how do I set up domainkeys for my account?" and "How do I set up SPF for my account?" and remove this question. It's not worth us trying to track down your problem until you've done those things.

Comment: thanks for your inrest and i given you below the SPF AND DOMIANKEYS Which set in my Hosting Server . i think its all right   DOMAIN KYE   20110303._domainkey.sulabhloan.com IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDa5OWJRHp/8Lwjypf7alxE8JxKRK/ZfG7drgkM rb+uhef1VNTb1JWWFjvuBUDIYBCVXDLPOqywjRLbe6r8mi7xpEBzbRy23G9za7e2hZLma7h/J+83 21fZUIVomJOekGCWg..."
sulabhloan.com IN TXT "v=spf1 exists:%{i}._spf.mailhostbox.com redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com"

Comment: @ paulmorriss ,as you can see my domainkey and spf is looks allright ... please help to solve my SPAM issue its very important ..

Comment: I would add this as comment, but I can't so I post it here: I think that the anti-spam algorithm of google use community to adjust itself. So, I'm not sure you can really do something about it now. I believe people will have to signal your email as "Not a spam" to be moved to secure email by google. However, that is only a belief and I haven't found a confirmation from Google.

Comment: OK, I thought you wanted to try the solutions suggested but didn't know how.

Comment: I am having the same problem for my new domain. All the prerequisite entries like SPF, PTR, MXLOOKUP & DKIM are done, also the IP is having good reputation but then also even a simple text mail is going in spam. I have hardly sent 10-20 mails from this new domain, that too transactional.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed your SPF and domain keys are set up correctly, and are valid for you emails?

If you send an email to `spf-test@openspf.org`, your email will be rejected, and the reply will contain details of the test results.

Certainly, I found that while I thought I had things configured correctly, because of the way my hosts were sending emails through a different server, I needed to make further tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your IP at mxtoolbox's supertool?

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your hosting company does not enable DKIM for your domain by default.

I assume that you are using CPANEL software. To enable DKIM on Cpanel [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2H2A8XNZkA).

[Read More about DKIM and why it is important](https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dkim).

Or if you use VPS then you should setup it your own, but it depends what server software do you use.

For more targeted help please provide info about what hosting do you use. And what type of server software do they run.

Answer (score -1):

In order to stop the emails going to your spam folder in Gmail - which is your question - make a filter for that domain and choose - never spam, as the filter.

If you want your domain to not be spam anymore, which is not your question - clean your server from hacked spammy scripts, and change to a dedicated IP, not shared. Or your friends on your shared IP can screw you over.