# Gmail is marking my emails as SPAM - Please help

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention, gmail, spam-blocker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

gmail is marking my emails as SPAM

I used the great service: isNOTspam.com to check my email against spam

I got the following

But I don't understand what it means please help me!   thanks

```
Thank you for using isNOTspam.

The isNOTspam team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : neutral
Sender-ID Check : neutral
DomainKeys Check : pass
DKIM Check : pass
SpamAssassin Check : ham
==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname: mail-gx0-f193.google.com
Source IP: 209.85.161.193
mail-from: no-reply@codepigeon.com
---------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=no-reply@codepigeon.com
DNS record(s):
codepigeon.com.         14399   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:108.163.232.130 ?all"


----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=no-reply@codepigeon.com
DNS record(s):
codepigeon.com.         14399   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx ip4:108.163.232.130 ?all"


----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=no-reply@codepigeon.com
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=._domainkey.

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=no-reply@codepigeon.com
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=._domainkey.

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.2.5 (2008-06-10)

Result: ham (03.9points, 10.0 required)

   pts rule name              description
   ---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


   * -1.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low
   *      trust
   *      [209.85.161.193 listed in list.dnswl.org]
   *  1.2 SPF_NEUTRAL SPF: sender does not match SPF record (neutral)
   * -0.0 DKIM_VERIFIED Domain Keys Identified Mail: signature passes
   *      verification
   *  0.0 DKIM_SIGNED Domain Keys Identified Mail: message has a signature
   *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
   *  0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
   *  2.5 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16 BODY: HTML: images with 1200-1600 bytes of words
   *  1.1 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from
draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):
==========================================================

"pass"
   the message passed the authentication test.

"fail"
   the message failed the authentication test.

"softfail"
   the message failed the authentication test, and the authentication
   method has either an explicit or implicit policy which doesn't require
   successful authentication of all messages from that domain.

"neutral"
   the authentication method completed without errors, but was unable
   to reach either a positive or a negative result about the message.

"temperror"
   a temporary (recoverable) error occurred attempting to authenticate
   the sender; either the process couldn't be completed locally, or
   there was a temporary failure retrieving data required for the
   authentication.  A later retry may produce a more final result.

"permerror"
   a permanent (unrecoverable) error occurred attempting to
   authenticate the sender; either the process couldn't be completed
   locally, or there was a permanent failure retrieving data required
   for the authentication.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

From no-reply@codepigeon.com Wed Mar 14 13:43:34 2012
Return-path: <no-reply@codepigeon.com>
Envelope-to: check@isnotspam.com
Delivery-date: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 13:43:34 -0500
Received: from mail-gx0-f193.google.com ([209.85.161.193])
   by s15387396.onlinehome-server.com with esmtp (Exim 4.71)
   (envelope-from <no-reply@codepigeon.com>)
   id 1S7tAc-0000Uo-Cp
   for check@isnotspam.com; Wed, 14 Mar 2012 13:43:34 -0500
Received: by ggki26 with SMTP id i26so941402ggk.4
   for <check@isnotspam.com>; Wed, 14 Mar 2012 11:43:29 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
   d=codepigeon.com; s=google;
   h=date:to:from:reply-to:subject:message-id:x-priority:x-mailer
    :mime-version:content-transfer-encoding:content-type;
   bh=yYAEachAACAdByYlYzx5ByG3p3QEOATs2nV+CJqQAkE=;
   b=Rt0VOOwVgNlcmKDrv9kR1Z0tKdofOYlLhOCjGzbzmtFq9gMKB1F68HnLsEa8KmZ8du
    m2fpskmyHNc6tzi3byo1mzwY+3cZ98qHo3cQGDLGru9bPFkqSggKazs2IdG/edgA8Blq
    hJRDqtGZyyXx+c05/BE7HR7RkvgFjBYVMmHmE=
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
   d=google.com; s=20120113;
   h=date:to:from:reply-to:subject:message-id:x-priority:x-mailer
    :mime-version:content-transfer-encoding:content-type
    :x-gm-message-state;
   bh=yYAEachAACAdByYlYzx5ByG3p3QEOATs2nV+CJqQAkE=;
   b=UXiptOG3Poovfon48iUQYGz9CxPNKUSisoQfAfHizz0Jc6JKevF3ldAn0T2J2j7vQ8
    duQ0uL3ZsjtZYyjP3ZJMdZWlmVtpCjS4AtOp26nEirKmhlSAilp9tlA9cHvX0mgJWgPG
    RKeoKe7oVMi4r6A5MX06u0blYhktg5dRatRJtGUb+tpm2Ojhp6F4zr23WpxjghbL0Uv4
    K2+NTFG/SU/hW7ccru4YT8ZPBPlsaSr2PGJYCqXKLVwikG78gfue5J9OWpTytNSXdNq8
    6KoBfZNFNXQWZgcRrg8PS0iQ9gnethf2981mufYdRLTESg1d8hJLH/5HjehqIpJvlF9g
    VK1g==
Received: by 10.224.189.12 with SMTP id dc12mr4429122qab.22.1331750608913;
   Wed, 14 Mar 2012 11:43:28 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from app.codepigeon.com (s1.om-p.com. [108.163.232.130])
   by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id dv7sm10068000qab.15.2012.03.14.11.43.25
   (version=SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
   Wed, 14 Mar 2012 11:43:26 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 13:43:23 -0500
To: check@isnotspam.com
From: CodePigeon <no-reply@codepigeon.com>
Reply-to: CodePigeon <no-reply@codepigeon.com>
Subject: Confirm your registration to codepigeon
Message-ID: <7ff92e6ef02ae4c6048a9ce9ff1e86a5@app.codepigeon.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
X-Gm-Message-State:     ALoCoQlgrwBKD7dgmYJtBAQ7suyINxOBnBprwoC8Alozo9L2vAhlujKGnLI5SRpkeLx9hh0vaEmM
X-DKIM-Status: pass (codepigeon.com)

<img src="http://app.codepigeon.com/images/pigeon.png" />
   <h3>Thank you for joining CodePigeon.</h3>
   <b>To confirm your registration,  <a     href="http://app.codepigeon.com/confirm_registration/4f60e6cac2df4">click here</a></b><br>    <br>

   For your records, your username is: <b>check@isnotspam.com</b><br/><br/>

   Codepigeon is a service which allows you to edit code snippets online and embed them on your website. You don't have to handle differents FTP accounts anymore.
   <br/>
   Store your data on CodePigeon and quick edit content on your website
   <br/><br/>
   CodePigeon can embed html/javscript code and PHP code. Transactions are secure<br>

   If you have any questions, feel free to visit our FAQs and support discussions at https://www.codepigeon.com/help.<br><br>

   Twitter: www.twitter.com/CodPign<br>
   Facebook: www.facebook.com/codepigeon<br><br>

   Thanks,<br>
   The Codepigeon Team<br><br>

   <i>If you have received this email and didn't registered on CodePigeon, it is likely that another user entered your email address by mistake. If you didn't initiate the request, ignore this email and do nothing.</i>
```

Comment: Are you sending from within gmail at www.gmail.com or are you using pop or imap access to send from an email client?

Comment: its from the signup form located at http://app.codepigeon.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any big problem but Spamassassin is giving three hints on how to make the email look better:

- you get 2.5 points for having an image and only a few words. Remove the image or increase the text length
- you get 1.1 points for your formatting. Your Email is not correct HTML (e.g., is missing the `<html>` tag
- you get 1.2 points because you are not sending from what you specify in SPF record

Comment: Verify SPF record
Domain of mail sending server should match from and reply-to field of sent mail
Additonally authenticate domain ownership in google apps