# How did my email end up in spam? Spam only filters this specific email, other email contents work

Tags: email, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

My website has users buy our products and when the purchase completes, it sends the user an email. However, this email always ends up in spam! When the user first registers, the site also sends an email, this email however is not filtered and goes into the normal inbox. I'm not quite sure why this is so, gmail vaguely tells me that " It's similar to messages that were detected by our spam filters."

So I'm thinking that I need to reword the following email better. Can I get some tips? Or could something else be causing this?

[image]

thanks!

here's the unformatted email:

```
Delivered-To: mugenex69@gmail.com
Received: by 10.112.32.98 with SMTP id h2csp61953lbi;
        Tue, 20 Mar 2012 21:09:13 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.180.79.72 with SMTP id h8mr22836827wix.1.1332302953175;
        Tue, 20 Mar 2012 21:09:13 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <contact@website.com>
Received: from mail26.elasticemail.org (mail26.elasticemail.org. [178.32.180.26])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id 6si518487wiz.41.2012.03.20.21.09.12;
        Tue, 20 Mar 2012 21:09:12 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of contact@website.com designates 178.32.180.26 as permitted sender) client-ip=178.32.180.26;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of contact@website.com designates 178.32.180.26 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=contact@website.com; dkim=pass header.i=@website.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; bh=qjc8jxQuGy9pLN1YV9TR2PHQYKg=;
 c=relaxed/relaxed; d=website.com; s=api;
 h=DomainKey-Signature:MIME-Version:From:To:List-Unsubscribe:Subject:Date:Reply-To:Message-ID:Content-Type;
 b=Odt+nYhjntXPl7JPVHeJWjkStemt6so+FPVYY6oMKziMFzmW8YiLhN8WwSLY0faMcn/rirKsO2dOm/kvcHlqUJC7ldhaydE6bPekkBDa9kBovlGwPNm6xy9QWPP9I1fXDLDCwqqeAXv8kN0daXbh3pVyqWNUOk5cgQ35OgpQpKI=
DomainKey-Signature: q=dns; a=rsa-sha1; c=simple;
 d=website.com; s=api;
 h=MIME-Version:X-Mailer:From:To:X-Priority:List-Unsubscribe:Subject:Date:Reply-To:Message-ID:Content-Type;
 b=F7NNZIEyEV+64uYD8pVpe91WLP19Tw2Whk4OKpkLeAfkmrNIA7AjP0XYU1JWTlEyibHQJjjbhR62I3MvVJBSGp75eWfOuwb2AqYWZ/jAlMWznnfQLVv7OlYJsErGxYP6GUNNcuJaqlTPFDanJwtaEvR+tqXZRB7xrUisMd8lq2I=
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: email.website.com
From: "Website Contact" <contact@website.com>
To: mugenex69@gmail.com
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
List-Unsubscribe: <http://email.website.com/tracking/unsubscribe?msgid=su6g-8kfd0s0g>,
 <mailto:unsubscribe+su6g-8kfd0s0g@bounces.elasticemail.net?subject=unsubscribe>
Subject: Website Tickets: event
Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 04:09:17 +0000
Reply-To: "Website Contact" <contact@website.com>
Message-ID: <4tlaxecj2jy8.su6g-8kfd0s0g@email.website.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_3F77_7A0DF805.A8C886C0"


------=_NextPart_000_3F77_7A0DF805.A8C886C0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

SGVsbG8hIAoKIEhlcmUgYXJlIHlvdXIgdGlja2V0KHMpIGZvciBDVEFTIGVDc1RBU3kgMjAxMjog
CgpodHRwczovL2NhbXB1c2FtcC5jb20vP3RpY2tldHMvNy95aGloZ3Znd3Z3cWR3cXhtdnQKClNp
bXBseSBicmluZyBpdCB3aXRoIHlvdSBvbiB5b3VyIHNtYXJ0cGhvbmUsIG9yIHByaW50IHRoZSB0
aWNrZXQgb3V0IHRvIGJlIHNjYW5uZWQgYXQgdGhlIGV2ZW50LiBFbmpveSwgYW5kIHdlIGFwcHJl
Y2lhdGUgeW91ciBwdXJjaGFzZS4KClNpbmNlcmVseSwKVGhlIENhbXB1c0FtcCBUZWFt
------=_NextPart_000_3F77_7A0DF805.A8C886C0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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------=_NextPart_000_3F77_7A0DF805.A8C886C0--
```

Answer (score 2):

It contains very little text with one link which is a spam flag.

The subject looks to be kind of spammy (?Website Tickets:?).

Personalize the saluation, you have the person's name from the sale, put it after **Hello** as a lot of spam contains impersonal salutations like this.

The word *ticket* is over featured, get a thesaurus and come up with something that doesn't make it sound like you're offering a fake lottery entry.

And reword your closing to be friendly but leave **Team** out of it.

**{Your} {company name} {advisory|computer help|security|sales|management|etc} Team**
has become the trailing *friendly* closure to a lot of virus/trojan carrier emails with noxious links and zipped infector files.

And at the bottom, there's a tracking bug.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases (that I know) for which the chances are really high that gmail will detect email as spam:
1. The sender (from header) is not the same as the "reply to" header
2. The sender (from header) is not who he claim he is (for example in case of email forward
3. The body is HTML-encoded (instead of plain text)

Comment: my email fits the 3rd case, but I can't help having html since there is a link provided.

Comment: You can supply a link using a plain text without encoding the body in HTML format.

Comment: can you explain that a bit more for me, I'm not sure if I understand how this works. thanks

Comment: don't confuse HTTP with HTML. Your email body can be plain text, or, it can be HTML code (which displays images, colors, tables etc). You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_email