# Prevent mail flagged as spam when switching mail servers (new SPF records)?

Tags: email, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

For our business, we send out a significant amount of newsletter alerts to customers that sign up for it on our website. We used to send this mail directly from our web server via PHP. But because the web server limited us to the number of emails we could send per day, we purchased a VM server at a different host (that doesn't throttle email) and we are going to use that account solely for sending out the emails.

Anyways, now that the SPF records are going to be different from what they used to be and the source mail server is different, what steps need to be taken to prevent these emails being flagged as spam?

I know in Gmail, it's pretty smart about determining if the person actually sending the email is sending it from the server it expects (for flagging Phishing emails, etc). We don't want that to happen to our emails. Just sending a couple test emails out, Gmail's shows the SPF record saying:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com:
XXX.XXX.23.176 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record
for domain of root@mail.newserver.com) smtp.mail=root@mail.newserver.com
```

So is there anything we need to do with regards to SPF records as we move forward?

Comment: Would suggest you take a look at www.mailchimp.com

Comment: Our emails we send out are custom tailored to EACH recipient based off of dynamic info in a database. Can mailchimp do that or do they just send out flat email templates?

Comment: They're one of the biggest companies in the field, so I imagine so.

Comment: @Jakobud Yes, Mailchimp can send customized mails. The subscriber lists contain e-mail, firstname and lastname by default but you can extend that with your own columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "new" SPF records?

Comment: I mean different/changed SPF records.