# Domain blocked in spamhaus

Tags: domains, spam

I registered a domain with bigrock.in a week ago.

During my website's development phase, I sent several mails using PHPMailer to test Gmail accounts. The HTML message body contained a link to my domain name.

Other than that, I cannot remember of any other place where I have used my domain. Now today my website development was finished (kinda) . So I wanted to test it.

I ordered a VPS, set up everything properly, only to see the following message :

[image]

After searching for hours on google, I figured that the url in my mails may have been the problem. (Were they?).

So I went to Spamhause Blacklist Removal Center, [here](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/). When I submitted my domain for removal, I got the following message :

[image]

Now this is getting irritating. I am not a spammer, I send mails only for register verification and similar purposes.

Why can I not remove it from their blacklist? What do I have to do to remove it?

Again, after searching google for hours, I couldn't even find their contact email adrress.

When (if) my domain gets delisted , what should I do in order to prevent this from happening again?

UPDATE : Mxtoolbox says that DBL listed my domain to blacklist because of `No IP queries`

Comment: DBL wouldn't block the domain for 'several emails' and your only option is to contact them. You should also check to see if your domain has been previously owned as that could also be the case. Not being banned is simple, don't spam emails out to anyone else but yourself, DBL doesn't block for nothing well normally.

Comment: @bybe That's one of the problems. How do I contact them ? :|

Comment: Well, simple... don't think you can, they have self expiration's and it bans get lifted in time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is difficult to tell what happened exactly, I can give you this:

http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Put your domain name in and you will see you are a lot of black lists.

*But not all is lost!*

It appears that your domain name resolves to 127.0.0.2 which is a private IP address. I did a dig for you.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> anonstreet.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14368
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 7, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;anonstreet.com.                        IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      A       127.0.0.2
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      SOA     s1.anonstreet.com. root.s1.anon$
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx a:anonstreet.com i$
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      MX      5 mail.anonstreet.com.
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      ns1.anonstreet.com.
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      ns2.anonstreet.com.
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      s1.anonstreet.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      ns2.anonstreet.com.
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      ns1.anonstreet.com.
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      NS      s1.anonstreet.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.anonstreet.com.    38332   IN      A       67.23.166.123
s1.anonstreet.com.      38332   IN      A       127.0.0.2
ns1.anonstreet.com.     172732  IN      A       67.23.166.123
ns2.anonstreet.com.     172732  IN      A       67.23.166.123

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.anonstreet.com.    38332   IN      A       67.23.166.123
s1.anonstreet.com.      38332   IN      A       127.0.0.2
ns1.anonstreet.com.     172732  IN      A       67.23.166.123
ns2.anonstreet.com.     172732  IN      A       67.23.166.123

;; Query time: 85 msec
;; SERVER: 74.4.19.187#53(74.4.19.187)
;; WHEN: Wed May 14 13:32:00 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 329
```

This line:

```
anonstreet.com.         38332   IN      A       127.0.0.2
```

and others indicates that your domain name is assigned to a non-routable private IP address. The A record must not ever be a private IP address. When the domain name is used such as in a web browser, a request is made to resolve the domain name to a routable IP address. A request is made to a DNS server which returns at minimum the IP address associated using the A record. If the IP address is non-routable or incorrect, then the original request cannot be satisfied. In your case, your A record is a non-routable IP address.

You mentioned that your host support noted that 127.0.0.2 is localhost. This is a loop-back address and cannot be used publicly such as in an A record. The localhost address is used for the server to refer to itself. This is normal and required but localhost is not routable and should not show up in the DNS entries. You need to update the A record to be your assigned IP address 67.23.166.123. I do not know what s1.anonstreet.com. is but you may also want to update this. This is not done in virtualmin. Your host should have a control panel to their DNS server. This is what you want to use.

You have a SOA record that should be removed. This is usually reserved to your host name servers. I may have to rethink on this. You will want to change your ns1.anonstreet.com to be dns1.bigrock.in and ns2.anonstreet.com to dns2.bigrock.in. I did a quick dig and this appears to be correct.

As a matter of rule, when you have a host, you do not want to allow access to the DNS (likely Bind) server on your system. You will need to populate the DNS server for proper functioning since your server will refer to it. But you do not want to make it publicly available. I always recommend that your DNS server never be used as a statement of authority (SOA) or accessible for security reasons. This is because DNS servers can often be compromised either directly or in a reflection attack. Instead, always use the host companies DNS servers for public work since they are properly secured.

I went to SpanHaus Zen and it told me that 127.0.02 is in the black list. This is common because under no condition should a non-routable private IP address be allowed access anywhere. This is what caused me to do a dig.

Get a real IP address assigned to your domain name and update your DNS. Your host should be providing this. You may have to contact support for this. Make sure that they do not assign a black-listed IP address. This is a valid request and should not be a problem. Once updated, I am sure you will be fine.

Comment: The guys at my webhost say that `127.0.0.2` is localhost IP. Whereas my VPS IP is `67.23.166.123` . I'm using VirtualMin , and I set up a virtual server. The IP setting in my virtual server show `127.0.0.2` . Shouldn't my website resolve to my VPS's IP? Also, Updated question

Comment: That address should not be available publicly. I updated the answer again. ;-) The short answer is that your A record and other DNS records should never use a private IP address or localhost.

Comment: I am setting up the DNS all over again. My domain registrar says that to use their DNS management service, I must point my domain to their name servers (dns1.bigrock.in,etc). I just now did it. Now if I add a A record pointing to my VPS's IP, will that be ok? Or do the nameservers need to be pointing to my VPS too?

Comment: I went back and looked at the dig info and they are right. You will need 2 name servers to serve as the statement of authority (SOA) and they provided one as dns1.bigrock.in. You need to remove your SOA record and change your ns?.anonstreet.com records to point to 2 host name servers. That would be dns1.bigrock.in and it appears that dns2.bigrock.in is your other name server.

Comment: I just did that. I have also added a A record with hostname `anonstreet.com` with value `67.23.166.123`. Will that work?

Also, my webhost team has contacted me that the website will now resolve to `67.23.166.123`. Now I just have to wait for DNS propogation right?

Comment: I just did a dig and it looks okay so far. You will also want to add a CNAME record for www pointing to anonstreet.com so that www.anonstreet.com will resolve too. It will take a while for this to change because of TTL (time to live) times. For example, I cannot hit your website yet, but that was because the browser was using a cached DNS record which will change in time.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if you are sending e-mails from your server, you will need to add an MX record in your hosts DNS pointing to anonstreet.com. You may need to experiment with this, but I am pretty sure this will work for you.

Comment: I have already added a `www` A record. But if you say, I will add a CNAME record too. Regarding the MX record, a MX record is present in Virtualmin DNS Records with the mail host as `mail.anonstreet.com`. Do I still need to add a MX record on the domain registrar's side? (Also, now only spamhaus lists be as spam, others have delisted my domain and ip)

Comment: You do not need a CNAME if you added an A record for wwww. That is okay. You should use one or the other but not both. Regarding the MX record, it needs to be publicly available for other SMTP servers to check so *yes* you should add an MX record to your hosts DNS server.

Comment: I have added the MX Record with the same values as the record in virtualmin , i.e. , zone=`anonstreet.com` , value=`mail.anonstreet.com`

Comment: I just checked dig. You set your MX record to mail.anonstreet.com which is good, but mail.anonstreet.com does not have an A record. Add an A record for mail.anonstreet.com with your IP address and I think you are done! Feels good doesn't it?

Comment: Just added a `mail.anonstreet.com` A record pointing to `67.23.166.123` . It doesn't feel good yet :P . I'll be cock-a-hoop when this all works lol. And I can't thank you enough, so +1 already.

Comment: Anytime brother! This is why I am here. I spent 30 years helping people do web stuff purely for the fun of it. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: That's what communities are for. Even the website I have developed, is a kind of community, made for public/private discussions. Btw, can you dig again? I just did a dig and everything seems fine. But spamhaus has still blocked my domain and IP. (they say that IP will be automatically removed in 3 days)

Comment: That is likely because DNS records are cached and have TTL times that have to expire before they are re-checked. Checking your current TTL times, this can be 5 minutes up to 10 hours. Yikes! Just did a dig again and it all looks good. Time will tell of course. I am here everyday as well as many other excellent people. Best of luck with your website!

Comment: Yep its working. I submitted applications to spamhaus for delisting my domain and IP, and it did. THanks a lot!

Comment: Anytime! I am glad it all worked out okay. It was good that it was simple and not another problem that we could not fix.

Answer (score 0):

DBL wouldn't block the domain for 'several emails' and your only option is to contact them. You should also check to see if your domain has been previously owned as that could also be the case. Not being banned is simple, don't spam emails out to anyone else but yourself, DBL doesn't block for nothing well normally.

The other possibility is that your using A VPS, Cloud or Mail server on an IP address that has once been banned.. The IP address which stores/sends your emails is 67.23.166.123 which is shared with pubcrawler and is listed in the [SBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20SBL) which is a good thing, if its a shared server then this could also be a possiblity that someone has used your domain to send out a load of emails without your knowledge.

Comment: I am using a VPS alright. But the weird thing is, I can send/receive mails through my server's IP with no problem at all.

Comment: DBL doesn't block sending or receiving.... they can mark your 'sent' email as spam meaning it goes into the spam inbox, nothing is blocked or deleted (And this is only a small percentage of customers, users). VPS often use a block of IP addresses, when a customer decides they no longer want that VPS the IP address is 'freed' and then made available to other customers, meaning if they been naughty then you could also be at risk for something you didn't do, sadly this is why you should start the VPN and check the IP before attaching a domain to it.

Comment: I see. Yes that is definitely happening, as all my mails go to spam box. So does that mean that my only option is to wait till the ban gets lifted?

Comment: Well, being marked as SPAM may be nothing to do with DBL.... Gmail has its own filters and certain siginals can mark it... like URLS being included in the emails and not sending the emails using smtp and using PHP, not using SPT, or Domain keys and so on... just because you notice an email in the spam box doesn't mean its DBL... See > http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam