# Emails sent via Amazon SES going to spam in Gmail

Tags: email, spam-prevention, gmail, amazon-aws

Firstly I have read this question **[How can I prevent my mail from being classified as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam)** -- I'm verified on Amazon SES and have DKIM enabled.

I'm sending emails via Amazon SES - on Worpdress (using a plugin MyMail).

I have for the past year been sending weekly newsletters which have been working fine, no problem.

For the past month I have been sending daily automated emails to subscribers (who have double opted in) who have asked for betting tips (horseracing). Each day these tips are generated from my clients database. The email consists of four tips and then links to betting pages on my clients site. There is an unsubscribe button on all emails.

**I have noticed in the past few days that Google is sending to spam all emails coming from this domain whether it be a weekly newsletter or these daily betting tips.** This wasn't happening before I started sending the daily automated emails. My emails stats haven't changed too drastically though but I presume that's cause most of the receivers aren't using Gmail.

My open rate is about 20% and the click rate about 50%. I realise the terms 'betting' and 'tips' probably flag as spammy but all of my subscribers asked specifically to be on this list.

How I can address this problem? Am I stuck between a rock and hard place owing to the nature of the content - betting and tips

Bearing in mind the subscribers want these daily tips, they signed up for them. I get the feeling these daily emails (not the weekly newsletter) are damaging the website domains reputation.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to approach this situation?

Comment: Sorry, but this question appeals to be duplicate because the nature of the question remains the same, even through the situtaion may slightly differ. If you can't find an appropriate answer in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam its because no one has left one 'yet'.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about betting being the issue. See Mailchimp knowledge base article on [spam filters](http://kb.mailchimp.com/delivery/spam-filters/about-spam-filters#What-Spam-Filters-Look-For) for a description of how spam filters work and what they look for.

Can you remove the word `betting` from your daily emails and still make them understandable? That seems to be your only option.