# SPF and DKIM vs email forwarding addresses: how to avoid being rejected as spam?

Tags: email, spam, domain-forwarding, dkim, spf

Situation: I am sending emails from `me@mydomain.com` to `alice@example.org`. My DNS for `mydomain.com` is correctly configured with an SPF record. The recipient at `example.org` is able to receive my emails just fine (it says "SPF: pass" in the headers).

Now, Alice configures `alice@example.org` to redirect any email to `bob@otherdomain.com`. So `alice@example.org` no longer has a mailbox or account attached to it, it's simply a forwarding address to `bob@otherdomain.com`.

I send an email to `alice@example.org` again. However, the receiving end at `otherdomain.com` now thinks the email is coming from `example.org` (as that's the last forwarding server or IP address), which of course does not have the SPF record that I have on `mydomain.com`. So it now marks my emails as **failed** for the SPF check, and puts in the spam folder.

So in short, the problem is: **Due to redirecting email (on which I have no influence) the final recipient erratically thinks my email fails the SPF check, and discards it as spam. Is there a way to avoid this?**

Also, I noticed sometimes that if I don't have a DKIM record (and not using DKIM) but the forwarding server does, then the recipient thinks my message failed the DKIM check as well. Whereas I don't even use DKIM, nor do I have a DNS record for this. It's the forwarding server (`example.org` in this example) that makes the recipient think the email should be DKIM signed.

(edit) Note that if I email to `bob@otherdomain.com` directly, the problem does not occur. My email is then considered to be valid (it passes the SPF check) and does not get filtered as spam. However I can't know in advance if someone is using a forwarding address.

Comment: Your question is missing vital information such as whom hosts the email, e.g Googe G Suite, Microsoft Online Exchange or if you host it include information about your setup, e.g cPanel with Spam Filter enabled. (include both send and receive setups).

Comment: @SimonHayter I am actually encountering this problem in several different situations. I'm not using Google or Microsoft. In two particular cases I'm sending emails from a website, using php's `mail()` function which uses the hosting provider's SMTP server. One of these happens to use cPanel, the other DirectAdmin. No spam filtering in either although I'd assume spam filtering only concerns incoming mail, whereas my problem is about outgoing mail.

Comment: @SimonHayter What I'm asking is: I have a SPF record properly set up. However often people are using forwarding addresses (which I can't tell from the address) and when I mail from A to B, it's automatically being redirected from B to C, and then C somehow thinks the mail originates from B instead of A. But B obviously does not have the right SPF record for my original sending address (A). **So C decides my email fails the SPF criterium, and discards it as spam. Is there a way to avoid this problem?** E.g. configure my SPF to just approve *all* senders? (which kinda defeats the purpose)

Comment: @RocketNuts this is actually a good question, however you haven't framed it properly in the original post.  If you can reword it to add the bold text as a question I would vote to take it off hold.

Comment: Well... sounds like your not sending emails authenticated using SMTP. SPF, DKIM and even domain keys are not a magic ward that doesn't make your email un-spam filterable. So I suspect when you say forwarded you mean 'sent on behalf' which is a internal sending method used when PHP mail or alternatives are used not using SMTP. Currently, I see no unique question here and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam would be the duplicate. Unless you can explain the actual setup of your server that makes the situation unique.

Comment: If you feel its unique then please edit the question and include more information about the setup and adding 'sent' header message would go a long way too.

Comment: @SimonHayter No it's not unique, unfortunately I encounter this problem in multiple environments, with very different setups. I'm feeling the problem is more fundamental. It involves the general case of emailing from a domain with SPF record (which I'd say is standard) to a forwarding/redirecting address, and then the recipient erratically thinking the forwarding/redirecting server is the originating server, instead of my original domain. This is regardless of setup or specific software. It seems to happen in general when people use forwarding or redirecting addresses (which is quite common).

Comment: @SimonHayter Eh, I meant, my specific situation is not unique. But yes the question is unique, it concerns specifically the troublesome combination of SPF + sending to forwarding/redirecting addresses. This has hardly anything to do with the other question you linked.

Comment: @SimonHayter I actually don't know if I'm sending authenticated using SMTP. I am just calling php's `mail()` function on my hosting server, and it sends the email flawlessly. If I send it directly to e.g. any yahoo or gmail address or whatever, and look in the headers of the received message, it explicitly says "SPF: pass". So that's all fine. However if I send to forwardingaddress@example.com which is configured to redirect any email to a yahoo of gmail address, if I then look in the headers (in the received message at yahoo or gmail) it says "SPF: fail".

Comment: Tip, always use SMTP when spam is incorrectly be marked. I administrate over 50 websites, some domains or emails are more sensitive than others, some work fine with php send without SMTP while some need them, and I can tell you from personal experience that Yahoo and AOL will in particular will reject the most emails sent using mail() compared to gmail and hotmail,

Comment: Currently your email is being flagged as SPAM... the question linked is the same question. SMTP will solve your issue. But, if you like edit the question and include the (email Internet Headers) and I suspect the server is not forwarding the email but sending on 'BEHALF' as it can't forward email without authentication, the header information will tell me and others, all they need to know about your issue.But you could try adding multiple IP addresses to the SPF records (just do a IP lookup on the internal relays), use https://www.spfwizard.net/ but SMTP is always best.

Comment: @RocketNuts Reading through this, I agree with Simon here that we'd need to see the headers, and if possible the mail server log on the final receiving end. He's also correct that sending email through PHP is not very reliable, it's mostly used for sending form data (such as a contact form) to a single email. You should use an SMTP server, most likely your hosting provider or ISP provides one for customers to use. You can just change your PHP code to use that  and see if it solves the problem. If not, please include the headers and mail server log so we can see the transaction.

Comment: @SimonHayter OK thanks Simon, I will try and get SMTP authentication working first. If the problem still occurs I will be back with headers of example emails. Am I correct in thinking that I need some separate email library, such as [Pear](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) in order to send emails with SMTP authentication? i.e. I can't do that with the regular php mail function, right? Or is that a matter of php / server configuration.

Comment: Yes PHPMailer supports SMTP e.g `$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com';` If you are using SHARED hosting then you should speak to their customer service, they will tell you how to send using SMTP, if using a content management system such as WordPress or Joomla, it has built in support or you can use one of the dozens of plugins.

Comment: There's two possible solutions: 1. example.org has to use Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS) to make the mail look as if it's coming from @example.org. That works in all cases, but destroys/garbles the actual sender. So Replies won't work unless example.org routes them back.; 2. check SPF/DKIM/DMARC on example.org and add an ARC record stating everything is fine. otherdomain should find that record and let SPF pass. However, this is based on trust and for me, e.g. GMail has trust issues and still lets mails fail if SPF fails.

Comment: @SimonHayter If you reopen the question, I can write up a longer/more detailed answer.

Comment: @mbirth, this question was closed for a couple of reasons, one not enough information and the second issue was because its most likely duplicate because we already have a broad question that attracts answers for all occasions. So if you think you have an answer that not answered in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam then, by all means, leave the answer within that question.

Comment: @SimonHayter With all due respect, the question has all needed information  and your linked question is about mails showing up as "spam" in general. This one here is about mails only showing up as "spam" WHEN FORWARDED to a third party. Which is a whole different issue (mainly with SPF) in itself.

Comment: The question linked was already broad (title) and therefore has been edited to make this more obvious.

Comment: It should be noted that forwarding is exactly the same as sending and the advice carries over from the first domain to the second domain, this again is pretty obvious. Also note that the question was closed in 2017 and as I previously mentioned you are more than welcome to leave an improved answer, in fact, its preferred old questions are refreshed and users are more than welcome to edit questions to appeal to more users, if relevant, which in your case you feel is important to address 'forwarding' which is technically the [same as sending](https://serverfault.com/a/163180/149388)

Comment: @SimonHayter It forwarding is technically the same as sending, would that imply that forwarding is fundamentally incompatible with SPF? If not, how is it supposed to work, considering the receiving end will think the email is coming from the forwarding server instead of the original domain, however it does of course still have a from-address @ the original domain.

Comment: I absolutely disagree why this question was closed. It contains all of the necessary information to understand the problem and give an answer. None of the additional information requested by @SimonHayter is necessary - in contrary, providing any of it would distract from the problem which is already precisely described in the question.
An answer discussing Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS), like given in mbirth 's comment, would be a helpful answer. SimonHayter please take your time to read the question carefully again, as you clearly did not understand it and please reopen it.

Comment: @mbirth if you gave a detailed answer on this subject anywhere else, please post a link here, thanks a lot!

Comment: To specify why I think the reasons to close this question are not valid:
1) https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam is completely different, it does not adress the forwarding/SPF problem.
2) The problem is independent of ISP, MTA software or recipient domain
3) No log information or headers are required to understand the problem.
4) "forwarding is exactly the same as sending" - what? If you are not familiar with SPF, DKIM, SRS or operating MTAs, please do not comment on this subject.

Comment: A specific case was asked at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135753/email-forwarding-to-gmail-and-spf